# Zeos 7 Failing to install

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-xe2, package, zeos

I have installed the Zeos 7 Beta on my own machine but it fails on my client's laptop. We're both running Delphi xe2, his is Entreprise, mine is Pro. His machine is running 64-bit windows 7, mine is running Window 7 32-bit.

When I do Compile all on ZeosDbo or ProjectGoup16 it seems to get through ZCore.dpk but then shows 2 fatal errors:

```
ZCore.dpk(1) E2225 Never-build package 'ZCore' must be recompiled 
ZParseSQL.dpk(33) E2202 Required package 'ZCore' not found
```

This is production code we are working on, so I hope we can find a solution and get back to working on this

Zeos forum thread: http://zeos.firmos.at/viewtopic.php?t=3633

Comment: David, yes, I asked a question on the Zeos forum first, and for a long time got no answer. Since this problem is stopping my client from being able to use his machine I was getting a bit frantic.

Comment: Arioch: I would love to give people credit for answers. I guess the problems I've come here for have been too obscure or vague. But I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Mark, please put "@" before name, like twitter does. That makes Stack OVerflow to aler the person, who's been replied. // to add to suggestions you've got at Zeos forum - did you tries SysInternals Process Monitor ? set the proper filter and youcan easily see all BPL-files used for exampel and additionally all folders they were searched in. Sometimes it helps. I also edited your post to include the link to the forum, let there be more interconnectivity within internet

Answer (score 2):

That is one error, the 1st one. The second is merely post-effect.
Perhaps you can do better than downloading beta ZIPs: until they have mature release you just can download each day "nightly" changes by version-control tools, like Git or SVN or whatever Zeos team is using.
Such errors are usually quickly fixed (they are simple) but long released(they are so moot that no one would bother making release for them).

Just open http://zeos.firmos.at/portal.php and read where to get most instant updates and how to report problems.

Actually - there it is, http://svn.code.sf.net/p/zeoslib/code-0/trunk/
Install TortoiseSVN and be on the edge until 7.0.1 or 7.0.2 final release

The page also says: **Please report bugs for this version to our brand new bugtracker on sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/p/zeoslib/tickets/**
Please do. Open Source is about participating. At least participate by registering bugs.

About the essence of problem read [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/E2225_Never-build_package_%27%25s%27_must_be_recompiled_%28Delphi%29) and "See Also" section.
Someone should decide about package binary update strategy. And the decision should be kept for all packages (okay, you can mix it in some conditions, but that is not to be suggested). So basically you have three choices:

1. Make your own decision and put all Zeos packages into the strategy of your choice. That puts the responsibility upon yourself to maintain [this fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) for a while until you come back to vanilla ZeosDB.
2. Report the bug to ZeosDB team and ask their suggestion, then change those settings for all the packages as suggested by them.
3. Report the bug to ZeosDB team and wait until they'd fix it in their SVN and then do SVN Update.

   - Personally i'd go with 1 option, but i am ready to be FLOSS libraries co-developer.
   - Option 3 would be the most slow yet the most easy for you.
   - Option 2... well... i can not see why you should choose that, except for trying to avoid version controls at any cost, which is bad idea per se.

I also suggest you to read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html
That would help you effectively communicate at ZeosDB forums - and you'd have to if you want to be "on the edge" (and if you do not - then wait for public release like 7.0.2).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Arioch. I have tried SVNing the latest code, that made no difference. Tried lots of things. I'm just hoping someone who has has a similar problem might recognize the symptoms and offer a solution.

Comment: Solution is simple, you should set all packages either to automatic build or to explicit build. The problem is that you don't know which was intended. Actually that is ultra-simple problem, but if you cannot read Delphi documentation linked above to solve it - then i'd say you should not make any changes to library. And that means you should report the issue to ZeosDB bug tracker and wait for them to upload the fix into SVN. Link is given above - create the ticket about your issue and ask that SVN be updated. Watch their reaction.

Comment: You may try to ask your question not like "oh god what should i do" but like "which packages should be set to "re-build explicitly" and which to "re-build automatically as needed", then they at least might tell you what is their intension.